# setting z-limit on surfplot in PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am making a 3D surfplot in pgfplots, and my situation is described by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{width=12.5cm,height=8.75cm, grid style=dashed, tick label style={font=\Large}, label style={font=\Large}}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] %needed for the MiKTeX compiler

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,  xlabel=\Large{$x$},ylabel=\Large{$y$}, zlabel=\Large{$z$}, view/v=55]
\addplot3[surf] coordinates{(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0) (0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5) (0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5) };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I wish to manually decide what the limits on the z-axis should be, regardless of what the coordinate-values are. E.g. I want to force them to be {0, 0.1}. Is there a way to accomplish this in pgfplots?

Best,
Niles.

Comment: do you mean `zmin` and `zmax`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Chris (cmhughes), you can set the limits `xmin` and `zmax` for the plot when you `\begin{axis}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{width=12.5cm,height=8.75cm, grid style=dashed, tick label style={font=\Large}, label style={font=\Large}}

%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] %needed for the MiKTeX compiler

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,  xlabel=\Large{$x$},ylabel=\Large{$y$}, zlabel=\Large{$z$}, view/v=55,zmin=0,zmax=.1]
\addplot3[surf] coordinates{(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0) (0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5) (0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5) };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]